# Rails key-value store always re-serialize the stores on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, key-value, key-value-store

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    store :options, accessors: [:bla, :blaa, :blaaa]
end
```

In the console:

```
Car.create(name: "aventador")

car = Car.last
=> #<Item id: 5839, name: "aventador">

car.options_changed?
=> false

car.save
(0.3ms) UPDATE "cars" SET "updated_at" = '2013-03-27 15:26:05.435320', "options" = '--- {}'
```

Nothing changed, the store wasn't accessed. Why is it re-serializing the **options store** every time the record is saved?

Comment: I guess updated_at means the last save, not the last change.

Comment: updated_at is expected, I don't understand why it has to reserialize the options store if they did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a feature: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8328

It's done this way because there is a way to change the data within these stores without marking them as dirty. For this reason, they chose to always re-serialize them. It might change in the future.